# How to switch jQuery class in HTML based on Radio Button choice

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, radio-button

I have a jQuery class that manipulates an image whenever it is applied to it, like this:

```
<div>
  <img src="cat.jpg" alt="If you can see this, then Javascript may be disabled." class="myJQclass1" />
</div>
```

This works perfectly on its own, however I also have 2 other jQuery classes: `myJQclass2` and `myJQclass3`, these manipulate the image differently than `myJQclass1`.

What I’m trying to do is create 3 radio buttons and the user will be able to switch the class used depending on what radio button they select (this will change how the image looks).

This is my code so far:

```
<script>
function check(effect) {
    document.getElementById("answer").value=effect;
}
</script>

<form>
<input type="radio" name="effect" onclick="check(this.value)" value="myJQclass1">Change Colour<br>
<input type="radio" name="effect" onclick="check(this.value)" value="myJQclass2">Change Brightness<br>
<input type="radio" name="effect" onclick="check(this.value)" value="myJQclass3">Change Contrast<br>

 <br>
 <div>
  <img src="cat.jpg" alt="If you can see this, then Javascript may be disabled." class="answer" />
 </div>
</form>
```

This isn’t working, I think I’m making a basic error, but I’m not sure what it is. 
I’ve never worked with radio buttons nor jQuery before, so I would really appreciate any help with this.

Thank you in advance!

Comment: If none of the answers worked or you are still facing trouble, let me know so I can help

Comment: There is no ID of `answer` in your HTML. You cannot use `getElementById('answer')` and provide a class as you did in your example above. Also you can't change the class of an element by providing it with a class to the `value` attribute.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use jQuery [removeClass()](https://api.jquery.com/removeclass/)/[addClass()](https://api.jquery.com/addclass/). Use the overload of `removeClass()` which allows you to remove multiple classes. Then add the class passed into the function

```js
function check(effect) {
    $('.answer').removeClass('myJQclass1 myJQclass2 myJQclass3');
    $('.answer').addClass(effect);
}
```

```css
.myJQclass1{
  color:yellow;
  }
.myJQclass2{
  color:green;
  }
.myJQclass3{
  color:blue;
  }
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script>

</script>

<form>
<input type="radio" name="effect" onclick="check(this.value)" value="myJQclass1">Change Colour<br>
<input type="radio" name="effect" onclick="check(this.value)" value="myJQclass2">Change Brightness<br>
<input type="radio" name="effect" onclick="check(this.value)" value="myJQclass3">Change Contrast<br>

 <br>
 <div>
  <img src="cat.jpg" alt="If you can see this, then Javascript may be disabled." class="answer" />
 </div>
</form>
```

Answer (score 1):

You could simplify things a bit more:

```js
$('input:radio').click(function() {
  var index = $(this).index('input:radio') + 1;
  $('.answer').attr('class', 'answer myJQclass' + index);
});
```

```css
.myJQclass1 {
  color: red;
}
.myJQclass2 {
  color: blue;
}
.myJQclass3 {
  color: green;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<form>
  <input type="radio" name="effect" />Change Colour
  <br/>
  <input type="radio" name="effect" />Change Brightness
  <br/>
  <input type="radio" name="effect" />Change Contrast
  <br/>
  <br/>
  <div>
    <img src="cat.jpg" alt="If you can see this, then Javascript may be disabled." class="answer" />
  </div>
</form>
```